# Crack between tire tread

Tags: cracking

I recently bought a used car and saw two cracks between treads on the front left side tire. Otherwise tires are in good condition with lots of life left. No cracks on other tires.

Is there anything to worry about? Can i use tire glue etc that are available in Canadian tire?
And is it safe only to change one tire?

Thanks,
Raman[image]

Answer (score 3):

Those long cracks at the bottom of the tread mean you need to replace the tire... it is older than you think and/or has been run with an incorrect pressure.

It is not suitable for gluing.